# How can I read User Entitlements using REST Web Api for VSTS

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops

How can I read User Entitlements using REST Web Api for VSTS?

Currently my code is like this but not getting result.

```
 var accountUriString = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/";
                Uri accountUri = new Uri(accountUriString);

                LicensingHttpClient licensingHttpClient = new LicensingHttpClient(accountUri, vssCredentials);
                Task<AccountEntitlement> accountEntitlementAsync = licensingHttpClient.GetAccountEntitlementAsync();
                var accountEntitlement = accountEntitlementAsync.Result;
                var license = accountEntitlement.License;
```

Comment: used uri: https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/ also but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
String collectionUri = "https://{account}.visualstudio.com";
VssCredentials creds = new VssClientCredentials();
creds.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), creds);
var licensingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<LicensingHttpClient>();
var accountEntitlement = licensingHttpClient.GetAccountEntitlementAsync().Result;
var license = accountEntitlement.License;
```